# What is tDPL in SDRAM timing and how is it violated?

Tags: simulation, sdram

The datasheet describes the tDPL as "Input Data To Precharge" time. However, it does not show it on any timing diagram. With an SDRAM controller I am getting this error: "tDPL violation during Precharge" during simulation. The SDRAM verilog model is connected to the SDRAM controller.

What is tDPL? And what does it mean in page and non-page mode. By page mode I am talking about burst mode where we can read/write whole row and not fixed number of columns.

This question is about single data rate SDRAMs.

Comment: Might be useful to link to the datasheet

Comment: I am not really sure but are you sending a precharge command when you get this error? As a tip, a lot of the timing parameters are standard (because they come from an SDRAM specification such as PC100 or something) so you may find help looking at datasheets for other SDRAM or at one of the SDRAM specifications (such as PC100).

Comment: yes, the error happens on the clock edge where precharge command is being applied during a page write burst mode.

Comment: I found some datasheets that actually show tDPL. The URL's are cumbersome. But try searching for Hynix SDRAM HY57V56820F(L)T(P) Series. Not sure it will help, but it might. You could also just add a wait state after your last write before you issue the precharge command. I think the problem is that precharge closes the page, so you need to wait one or two clocks after the last write before you close that page. Otherwise data will be lost.